# Data Manipulation, Looping to add columns

Tags: r

I have asked this question a couple times without any help.  I have since improved the code so I am hoping somebody has some ideas!  I have a dataset full of 0's and 1's.  I simply want to add the 10 columns together resulting in 1 column with 3835 rows.  This is my code thus far:

```
# select for valid IDs
data = history[history$studyid %in% valid$studyid,]

sibling = data[,c('b16aa','b16ba','b16ca','b16da','b16ea','b16fa','b16ga','b16ha','b16ia','b16ja')]

# replace all NA values by 0
 sibling[is.na(sibling)] <- 0

# loop over all columns and count the number of 174
apply(sibling, 2, function(x) sum(x==174))
```

The problem is this code adds together all the rows, I want to add together all the columns so I would result with 1 column.  This is the answer I am now getting which is wrong:

```
b16aa b16ba b16ca b16da b16ea b16fa b16ga b16ha b16ia b16ja 
   68    36    22    18     9     5     6     5     4     1
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe `apply(sibling, 1, function(x)sum(x==174))` helps. Please read `?apply` (read about the `MARGIN` argument).

Comment: The reason you keep getting minimal help is that you keep posting non-reproducible examples!

Comment: How do you get the result you post here? You wrote your dataset consists of 0 and 1 - in that case your `apply` command should report just zeros, isn't it?! Somehow it's difficult to see what data you have and what you want to get as result.

Answer (score 0):

In `apply()` you have the MARGIN set to 2, which is columns.  Set the MARGIN argument to 1, so that your function, sum, will be applied across rows.  This was mentioned by @sgibb.

If that doesn't work (can't reproduce example), you could try first converting the elements of the matrix to integers `X2 <- apply(sibling, c(1,2), function(x) x==174)`, and then use rowSums to add up the columns in each row: `Xsum <- rowSums(X2, na.rm=TRUE)`.  With this setup you do not need to first change the NA's to 0's, as you can just handle the NA's with the `na.rm` argument in `rowSums()`

Comment: This is the closest I have gotten!  The answer is correct, except I get one long row when I want this to be a column.

Comment: use the t() function -- it'll turn a row into a column, or vice versas (t for transpose).  That work?